# Can I prevent Xcode displaying main.m when it hits an exception?

Tags: xcode, debugging, exception

XCode jumps from the Project Navigator in to the Debug Navigator and nearly always switches to main.m. Then you have to navigate back to Project view and select the source you were working on.

I thought Behaviours might help, but couldn't see any relevant option there.

Comment: It doesn't do that for me.

Comment: Hmmm, OK thanks, needs further investigation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have setup my projects to have (at least) three tabs. One tab where I do stuff, another tab called `Build Results`, a third tab called `Debugger`. Create a tab with CMD-T, edit the tab name by double clicking where the name shows.

The Behaviours are set up for `Build` to switch to the `Build Results` tab. `Running` will switch to the `Debugger` tab. `Exits unexpectedly` will define what to display when an exception occurs. The settings for `Running` are show in the picture

This way my working tab will remain on the line where I am editing and the `debugger` tab can jump to where it wants to jump to.

[image]

Did you set up a sybolic breakpoint to symbol `objc_exception_throw`? That should stop at the line where the exception did occur, long before main.m is reached.

Comment: Thanks very much, that helped a lot. Occasionally when the breakpoints get confused I've done a SElect-All delete, I guess I deleted the symbolic one too.